# Mako templates inline if statement

Tags: python, templates, mako

I have a template variable, c.is_friend, that I would like to use to determine whether or not a class is applied.  For example:

```
if c.is_friend is True
<a href="#" class="friend">link</a>

if c.is_friend is False
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Is there some way to do this inline, like:

```
<a href="#" ${if c.is_friend is True}class="friend"{/if}>link</a>
```

Or something like that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Python's normal inline if works:

```
<a href="#" ${'class="friend"' if c.is_friend else ''}>link</a>
```

Comment: +1, too bad there's not a better way to do this than putting, for example, HTML markup inside a Python string...

Comment: Would be more beautiful if the meaningless "else" case could be discarded.

Comment: this also has a problem with quoting. `${'value="+val+"' if val is not None else ''}` does not work out (you need parts keeping the `"` and parts quoting html chars).

Comment: @kratenko you can use `str.format()` to get around some of that

Comment: @IanHunter I had some problems using `str.format()` because using {} inside Mako's ${} is complicated; apparently Mako stops parsing the expression after finding the first }.

Answer (score 4):

## More General Solution

If you need to come up with a more general solution, let's say you need to put a variable called `relationship` inside the class tag instead of a static string, you could do it like this with the old string formatting:

```
<a href="#" ${'class="%s"' % relationship if c.has_relation is True else ''}>link</a>
```

or without string formatting:

```
<a href="#" 
% if c.has_relation is True:
class="${relationship}"
% endif
>link</a>
```

This should work for Python 2.7+ and 3+

---

### WARNING (for older versions)

#### Pay attention to the `{}` inside `${}`!

The solution with the ternary operator mentioned by Jochen is also correct but can lead to unexpected behavior when combining with `str.format()`.

You need to avoid `{}` inside Mako's `${}`, because apparently Mako stops parsing the expression after finding the first `}`. This means you shouldn't use for example:

- `${'{}'.format(a_str)}`. Instead use `${'%s' % a_str}`.
- `${'%(first)s %(second)s' % {'first': a_str1, 'second': a_str2}}`. Instead use
  `${'%(first)s %(second)s' % dict(first=a_str1, second=a_str2)}`

Comment: I've used this line in a mako template without any issue, so perhaps they have fixed the issue with {} inside ${}:
${f"{metric + ':':41}{score:{score_format}}"}